# Is shrink a safe online operation?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

We are planning to run the following space management command:

```
alter table XXX shrink space cascade
```

on a production database (Oracle 10g). The `XXX` table is a transactional table heavily used  for updates/inserts/deletes by many applications.

I am wondering if running the `shrink` command during the peak time (online) will cause a severe performance degradation, or may lock the table and so block all the applications?

Can you clarify the impact of the `shrink` command on the access to the databese table `XXX`?

Comment: Regardless of whether it's safe or not, don't do segment administration during peak hours. That's just not a good practice at all.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it the resizing of the high water mark requires an exclusive table lock, which in theory might not be a problem as it would be of very short duration. However if it has to wait on other transactions before it gets the lock it will block other transactions.

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2453756

However as the docs point out, you could run a shrink space compact, which does not move the HWM, and run the shrink later on when the system is known to be quiet: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#i2192484